# Attempting to standardise a may_alias idiom in C++?

Tags: c++, unions, strict-aliasing

From my understanding GCC and Clang both support: `__attribute__((may_alias))`

So I believe for example if I wanted to define a fallback type for say a 128-bit SSE type that works across GCC/Clang/MSVC on x64/ARM I could do something like:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define UNIONALIAS union
#else
#define UNIONALIAS union __attribute__((may_alias))
#endif


UNIONALIAS VI128
{
    uint64_t uint64[2];
    uint32_t uint32[4];
    uint16_t uint16[8];
    uint8_t uint8[16];
    int64_t int64[2];
    int32_t int32[4];
    int16_t int16[8];
    int8_t int8[16];
};
```

Now as far as I understand it currently all versions of MSVC will allow you via undefined behaviour to ignore strict aliasing rules and access the different types within that union and get what you 'would hope for' despite the C++ standard providing no guarantee etc.  With the attribute tag on GCC/Clang this will likely future proof the code on those compilers despite not being standard C++.

I suspect if something like this became a standard idiom then future versions of MSVC would surely take it into account even if they didn't adopt compatible attribute syntax - maybe they have something planned already?  Also maybe any future C++ standard would also make room to allow for a suitable transition if it directly added support for `may_alias`?

I use a fallback SSE type as an example but maybe an integer AVX2 one would have been better.  But the point remains is sometimes you do want to do things like this and the `memcpy` route may not be viable due to performance in debug builds and sometimes it can cause a lot of excessive typing and contorted effort really.

Apart from it being non standard (!) is there any major flaw in this approach, or my understanding current compiler behaviour regards this?

Comment: I mean via UB it lets you write to one field and read from another that aliases it.  From what I have found online and seen MSVC behaves this way and needs to otherwise it would break a lot of Win32 code.

Comment: In the [Clang documentation for attributes](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html), I cannot find `may_alias` in the list. I can only find it in the corresponding [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html). Are you sure that Clang also supports it?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, it does. See e.g. [the tests](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/test/CodeGenCXX/may_alias.cpp). Clang documentation is rather poor. However, they generally aim for compatibility with GCC extensions.